# Java vs JavaFx vs Android SDK in Intellij Idea

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, javafx, sdk

How should I choose among these buttons: Java vs JavaFx vs Android SDK in Intellij Idea start up? What are the difference among them? Can you guys explain to me? And if I intend to build an Android application, can I select the Java button? Pictures are shown as below...

How to choose?
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your image points out, you are about to create a new project. If you intend to create an Android project, then just click on the Android button, the IDE will create a basic project structure for you.

Comment: If I have already created an application in the 'Java' button, can it be accepted and run by the android mobile devices?

Comment: A simple Java project cannot... You can import your Java code into an Android project and use it there, but read some tutorials concerning Android applications in Java first, there are several differences between plain Java and Android.

Comment: I understand now... Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a Android projet, you need to use the Android button. This will setup all the requirements for the Android project to run on a mobile device.

The Java button creates a simple Java project unrelated to the Android framework.

JavaFX is a library to make desktop GUI. Pressing this button will setup a generate some template files ready to program with JavaFX.